# How do we really clean or pre-process Image for Image Classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a simple question to some of you. I have worked on some image classification tutorials. Only the simpler ones like MNIST dataset. Then I noticed that they do this

```
train_images = train_images / 255.0
```

Now I know that every value from the matrix (which is the image) gets divided by 255.0. If I remember correctly this is called normalization right? (please correct me if I am wrong otherwise tell me that I am right).

I'm just curious is there a "BETTER WAY","ANOTHER WAY" or "THE BEST WAY" to pre-process or clean images then those cleaned images will be fed to the network for training.

Please if you would like to provide a sample source code. Please! be my guest. I would love to look at code samples.

Thank you!

Comment: I think there is no "best" way. It all depends on the problem you are trying to solve. The reason for normalizing as I understand is to prevent the numbers from blowing up too quickly.

Comment: Pre-processing depends on what type of data you are dealing with,in case of Image we usually do Normalization.But in some cases you need to crop out image,or change it color space.In medical imaging,we need to do some extra work before feeding into the model.

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer is great! thank you! It gave me more info about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-processing images prior to image classification can include the followings:

- normalisation: which you already mentioned
- reshaping into uniform resolution (img height x img width): higher resoltuion leads to better learning and smaller resolution may lose important features. Some models have default input size that you can refer to. Also an average size of all images can be used too.
- color channel: 1 refers to gray-scale and 3 refers rgb-scale. Depending on your application you can set this.
- data augmentation: if your model is overfitting or your dataset is small, you can reproduce your dataset by altering original images (flipping, rotating, cropping, zooming..) to increase your dataset
- image segmentation: segmentation can be performed to highlight the area or boundaries that may benefit your application. For example, in medical image classification, some part of body maybe masked to enhance classification performance.

For example, I recently worked on image classification of lung CT scan images. For pre-processing, I have reshaped the images and made them gray-scale. Then I performed image segmentation to highlight the lungs in the images. And I normalised the image pixels to put into my classification model. Depending on your application, there may be other more pre-processing techniques you might want to consider.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I don't know why some guy disliked my question but my question really is important for me and I think people might have the same question. I'll be soon working on deep learning I just getting ready for it after finishing some stuffs.

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer is the best! I'll check it , but let us wait for others to answer I love to know more about from people. THANK YOU AGAIN! :D

Comment: wait hmmm. May I ask what you mean by masked? some part of the image maybe masked? Is it like the pixel can be somehow enhanced?

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. :) What I mean by masked image is that making the background pixels to be zero and leaving lung pixels non-zero. This will make only lung pixels appear and rest go black. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/CT-slice-and-lung-segmentation-masking-animal-2-A-Slice-from-reconstruction-of-one_fig3_333587428 this will show how masked lung CT scan image looks like. This allows the model to only learn the features of the lung, not the background, hence enhances the model's performance.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I get it... THANK YOU SO MUCH AGAIN!

Comment: Hello! I got one more question. If we're going to do some sort of training to a neural network. The things you mentioned above, should we all do it as a part of cleaning the image data for training? or some only? or like it's up to me to decide. Thank you!

Comment: Well, types of pre-processing for images really depends on your application and what you want to achieve out of it. For example, image segmentation is beneficial in many medical image processing but may not benefit other image classifications. Image segmentation may remove or reduce important features of the images. And making images in gray-scale also, if colors play an important role in distinguishing objects, then you wouldn't limit the color scale to only black and white.

Comment: As you learn more about image processing, you will learn some common pre-processing for specific tasks. I'd highly recommend checking out other people's work on image processing on Kaggle. You will learn alot from it. And when you apply pre-processing to training images, you should also apply the same processing to the testing images too. As the model would be fitted to the pre-processed images.

Comment: And sometimes, it's hard to tell if a particular pre-processing will benefit the case. One good way to determine this quickly is to try out pre-processing on some sample images and give it to a simple model (simplified version of your model). This will save your time in choosing the right pre-processing techniques.

Comment: Thank you so much! your answers are really precise and direct to the point! Thank you & God Bless you!